# How to add system alias?

Tags: shell, alias

I have this alias in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias grim='gvim --remote'
```

But this is not seen from ranger file manager, I believe that ranger runs a 'generic' shell skipping my `.zshrc`. I want to make this alias visible in every shell.

I added it to `~/.profile` and to `/etc/zsh/zshrc` but no effect. To be specific a got this message:

```
/bin/sh: grim: not found
```

Comment: Can you give details about your shell?

Comment: Did you restart the shell or `source` the appropriate config?

Comment: I use zsh. I have the alias in my .zshrc and it works. But this is not seen from ranger file manager, I believe that ranger runs a 'generic' shell skipping my .zshrc. To test my actions I open new terminal (by gnome-terminal), is it enough?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only interactive shells read a file that may contain alias definitions. If you want to use a nickname for a command in shell snippets executed by applications, an alias is not the right tool. Instead, write a wrapper script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gvim --remote "$@"
```

Call it `~/bin/grim` and make it executable. Make sure you have `~/bin` in your `PATH` (you can put the script in any other directory that's in your `PATH`).

If you want it to work for every user on the system, put it in `/usr/local/bin` instead, ensuring that that directory is in everyone's PATH.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file *alias.sh* in `/etc/profile.d` directory

Write the line

```
alias grim='gvim --remote'
```

inside that file *alias.sh*

This will create a system-wide customization.

Instead of *alias.sh* you can use any other filename ending with *.sh*

Comment: Any name for file in /etc/profile.d is acceptable?

Comment: @xliiv: yes name will work.

Comment: Alias from /etc/profile.d/name doensn't work either in bash or sh. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can hack ~/.config/ranger/commands.py and replace the last line in shell.execute():

```
self.fm.execute_command(command, flags=flags)
```

with

```
self.fm.execute_command("bash -c '" + command + "'", flags=flags)
```

It works for me.

Comment: Clever. And in the config folder, so not a hack in theory.

Answer (score -1):

Did you do something like? :

`source /path/to/.profile`